# elements get bigger when zooming in

Tags: html, css, web

Even though I've set a max width/height for my image element, it'll still extend upwards when I zoom in on the page. Any help here :)?

```
.column img {
    width: 80%;
    height:450px;
    max-height:450px;
    min-height:450px;
    max-width:80%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    box-shadow: 6px 6px 6px #000;
}
```

[website 100% view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atyPL.jpg)

[website 120% view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtgkx.jpg)

Comment: Could you add a JSFiddle with the code + images?  Are your images guaranteed to be square?

Answer (score 0):

**I know 1 way to solve this if you want with CSS only.**

With CSS: you can make break points in your page. So in resolutions that you set your page will be responsive. You can check [This](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) . And you can not use (%) for solve your problem. Only with px. If you set

`height:450px;width:450px;`

this will work for the circle but will not be responsive. And the px of width must be the same with height. And the [BootStrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) is some files that can help you with the responsive design.

Comment: Doesn't seem to have fixed my problem it simply makes all of my image elements different width's and heights instead :/